# TV series about what a real man should be able to do on Discovery channel

Tags: identify-this-movie, documentary

Does anyone know the name of a TV series/documentary that ran on Discovery channel and is featuring a British actor whose name I cannot recall but I do remember that he show all the stuff that a "real man" should be able to do, fix etc.

I remember the only episode I watched had several questions - how to diffuse a World war II bomb, how to court a lady and several other.

Comment: Are you sure it was on the Discovery Channel?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Discovery_Channel

Comment: Yeah, it aired on Discovery in Croatia. It's probably because in Europe Discovery doesn't air only its own documentaries but other as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This must be [James May's Man Lab](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00vs617). The mission statement (from the site):

> James May sets out to help modern man relearn some of the vital skills that are now in danger of being lost forever

I remember seeing episodes of it, not sure if it was on Discovery, probably the BBC.